# SQL query to split the Product Quantities order wise to specific constant threshold quantity?

Tags: sql-server

There is a list of products with quantities. Each product quantities must be splitted into specific constant quantity.

I have tried with the given list if the product quantity greater than the constant quantity , the result is fine. When the product quantity less than the constant , I am unable to derive the logic. Constant product Quantity is 650

```
SortOrder   ProductCode Quantity
1           PC1         1400
2           PC2         4500
3           PC3         1500
```

Given below code is working fine for this list.

```
SortOrder   ProductID   Quantity
1           PC1         650
1           PC1         650
1           PC1         100
2           PC2         550
2           PC2         650
2           PC2         650
2           PC2         650
2           PC2         650
2           PC2         650
2           PC2         650
2           PC2         50
3           PC3         600
3           PC3         650
3           PC3         250
```

But the problem is if the product quantity less than the constant value.

```
SortOrder   ProductCode Quantity
1           PC1         400
2           PC2         500
3           PC3         1300
4           PC4         300
5           PC5         500
```

The Result should be

```
SortOrder   ProductCode Quantity    Shift
1           PC1         400         A
2           PC2         250         A
2           PC2         250         B
3           PC3         400         B
3           PC3         650         C
3           PC3         250         A
4           PC4         300         A
5           PC5         100         A
5           PC5         400         B
```

sum of each shift should be equal to constant value

Please help me on this.

Comment: If the resulted quantity does not meets the constant , get the remaining quantity from the next product. For PC1 splitting 1400 into 650,650,100. for third row 100 is not equal to 650. hence get the remaining 550 from next product PC2.

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question if you would provide INSERT statements instead of the data in the table + DDL statements for all needed objects.

Comment: The query itself insert statements and DDL statements are available.

Comment: A bit unclear. If constant = 100, do you want to split 450 to 100+100+100+100+50? and if const = 500 then the value should remain 450?

Comment: Yes, You are right. Based on the constant we have to split them.if constant = 500 then the quantity will be 450(current product)+50(from next Product)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it with both samples and get the expected output, I used a recursive CTE to get the compensation quantity, let me know if you want me to write a deeper explanation of an specific part of the code.

```
DECLARE @Const INT = 650

;WITH nums AS (
    SELECT 1 as num
    UNION ALL
    SELECT num + 1 FROM nums WHERE num < 100
), compensation AS (
    SELECT *, 0 as Compensation, SortOrder as OD
    FROM #Temp_ProductQtyOrderList t
    WHERE SortOrder = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.*, CASE WHEN c.Quantity - Compensation < 0 THEN ABS(c.Quantity - Compensation) ELSE @Const - ((c.Quantity - Compensation)%@const) END, 
    CASE WHEN c.Quantity - Compensation < 0 THEN c.OD ELSE c.SortOrder END
    FROM #Temp_ProductQtyOrderList t
    JOIN compensation C ON c.SortOrder = t.SortOrder - 1 

), split1 AS (
    SELECT CASE compensation WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + num rn, b.*, t.SortOrder as OD
    FROM compensation t
    CROSS APPLY (
        VALUES(t.SortOrder, t.ProductID, @const)
    ) b (SortOrder, ProductCode, Quantity)
    join nums ON num <= (t.Quantity-compensation)/@const
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, t.SortOrder, t.ProductID, CASE WHEN Quantity > compensation THEN compensation ELSE Quantity END, OD
    FROM compensation t
    WHERE compensation > 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CASE compensation WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + (t.Quantity-compensation)/@const + 1, t.SortOrder, t.ProductID, (t.Quantity-compensation)%@const, sortorder
    FROM compensation t
    WHERE (t.Quantity-compensation)%@const > 0
)
SELECT SortOrder, RN, ProductCode, Quantity, CHAR(64 + DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY OD, CASE WHEN Quantity<@Const OR SortOrder<> OD THEN 999 ELSE rn END)) Shift
FROM split1
ORDER BY SortOrder, rn, ProductCode
```

**PS** Your own sample doesn't fit with your requirement:

> sum of each shift should be equal to constant value

I didn't find any reasonable criteria to repeat A and B shifts, so it will return shifts A, B, C, D and E for that sample input...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But Edited the question Please check how the result should be.

Comment: @Vinoth I updated the answer, please don't do that again, there is a huge difference between edit a question to improve the explanation and do it to add new requirements... also, you vandalized your own question removing useful information as your definitions and current approach

Comment: I am really sorry for that. But still the result is not coming.

Comment: The only difference I get with this approach and your sample data is the one I mentioned regarding duplicated shifts, could you be more specific than just "the result is not coming"?

Comment: If you replace the Shift formula to **CHAR(64 + ISNULL(NULLIF(DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY OD, CASE WHEN Quantity<@Const OR SortOrder<> OD THEN 999 ELSE rn END)%3,0),3) ) Shift** you will get the result exactly as your sample... but I'm not sure if you just want to reset this value to A every three shifts...

Comment: Please ignore the Shift

Comment: `SortOrder   ProductCode Quantity
1           PC1         400(not equal to 650 get next product's 250)        
2           PC2         250(adding with previous row will get 650)      
2           PC2         250(500-250)(not equal to 650 get next product's 400)       
3           PC3         400     
3           PC3         650     
3           PC3         250(not equal to 650 get next product's 400)        
4           PC4         300(this product quantity is 300 so 250+300 is 550 not equal to 650 hence get 100 from next product)

Comment: I fixed it when I added the shift? Did you test it??

Comment: I had an issue where more than two products was needed to fill a batch, but It was fixed in my last edit

Comment: Yes I tested it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191700/discussion-between-daniel-brughera-and-vinoth).

Comment: There is another logic to be incorporated in this. Shall I ask here or post it as a new question?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @const INT = 650;

SELECT       sortorder
           , productid
           , c.val
  FROM       #Temp_ProductQtyOrderList   AS l
 CROSS APPLY (   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY o.object_id) AS m
                   FROM sys.all_objects o
                   ) AS mult
 CROSS APPLY (SELECT quantity / (mult.m * @const) AS val) AS a
 CROSS APPLY (   SELECT CASE WHEN quantity < @const THEN quantity
                             WHEN val = 0 THEN quantity - @const * (mult.m - 1)
                             ELSE @const
                        END AS val) AS c
 WHERE       mult.m <= quantity / @const + 1 AND c.val > 0;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the objective not attained. Please consider the following 'SortOrder ProductCode Quantity
1 PC1 400
2 PC2 500
3 PC3 1300
4 PC4 300
5 PC5 500'

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But Edited the question Please check how the result should be.